# How can we prevent retrogradation of starch?

Tags: aqueous-solution, hydrogen-bond, carbohydrates, conformers, physical-organic-chemistry

Are there any additives which can prevent [retrogradation of starch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrogradation_(starch))? I have prepared 13% of starch solution along with 2% of NaCl. The results were bit better. The synthesized gel was flowable with some bubbles inside it, perhaps 2% of salt was more than enough. Coming back to my question, are there any better substances which can be used for this purpose?

Comment: I just saw a mention that stuff like Na+ *accelerates* it.